# FlexBox - absolute position behaves like fixed

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have a very basic task which seems like it should be easy to accomplish using any sort of GUI markup language that actually MAKES SENSE. Unfortunately, HTML/CSS is no such markup language.

In the example below.  I have a "Holy Grail" page layout that uses flexbox styling in CSS.  The main layout is okay... it even scrolls nicely. But when I add an element into the body (center/gold region) with absolute positioning, the position of the specific element behaves as-if fixed, not absolute.  In the code below, I have made this a div 128x128 and colored it #00ffff (cyan).  A sane person would think that the div would appear in the upper left hand corner of the main body region (the gold part)... however, flexbox appears to treat my absolute positioning as-if it were positioned FIXED instead.  The code below is all you need to demonstrate this problem.

I need a solution that behaves as expected.

```
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>FLEXBOX LAYOUT PROOF OF CONCEPT</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="layout__body">
    <main class="layout__content">
        <div id="absolutepositioned">MESSED UP</div>
        <div style="color: #00FFFF;"><b>the blue box should be here</b>    </div>
    </main>
    <nav class="layout__nav layout__columns">
        NAV ITEMS<br>
        NAV ITEMS<br>
        NAV ITEMS<br>
        NAV ITEMS<br>
        NAV ITEMS<br>
        NAV ITEMS<br>
        NAV ITEMS<br>
        NAV ITEMS<br>
        NAV ITEMS<br>
        NAV ITEMS<br>

    </nav>
    <aside class="layout__aside layout__columns">YOUR VIAGRA ADS HERE</aside>
  </div>
  <footer> FOOTER
  </footer>
</body>
<style>
  body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .layout__body {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .layout__content {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .layout__columns {
    flex: 0 0 12em;
  }
  .layout__nav {
    order: -1;
  }

  .layout__content {
    background: #3f3f00;
  }

  .layout__columns {
    background: green;
  }

  header, footer {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  footer a {
    flex: 1;
  }

  h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica;
  }

  #absolutepositioned
  {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 128px;
      height: 128px;
      background-color: #00ffff;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Try adding `position: relative` to `.layout__content`.

Comment: That works! thanks!  Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> An absolutely positioned element is an element whose computed position
>   value is absolute or fixed. The top, right, bottom, and left
>   properties specify offsets from the edges of the element's containing
>   block. (**The containing block is the ancestor relative to which the
>   element is positioned**.) If the element has margins, they are added to
>   the offset.

You need to add `position: relative` to the ancestor that you want to position the element in relation to, in your case, that's `.layout__content`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.layout__body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.layout__content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.layout__columns {
  flex: 0 0 12em;
}

.layout__nav {
  order: -1;
}

.layout__content {
  background: #3f3f00;
  position: relative;
}

.layout__columns {
  background: green;
}

header,
footer {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

footer a {
  flex: 1;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#absolutepositioned {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background-color: #00ffff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>FLEXBOX LAYOUT PROOF OF CONCEPT</h1>
</header>
<div class="layout__body">
  <main class="layout__content">
    <div id="absolutepositioned">FIXED!</div>
    <div style="color: #00FFFF;"><b>the blue box should be here</b> </div>
  </main>
  <nav class="layout__nav layout__columns">
    NAV ITEMS<br> NAV ITEMS<br> NAV ITEMS<br> NAV ITEMS<br> NAV ITEMS<br> NAV ITEMS<br> NAV ITEMS<br> NAV ITEMS<br> NAV ITEMS<br> NAV ITEMS<br>

  </nav>
  <aside class="layout__aside layout__columns">YOUR VIAGRA ADS HERE</aside>
</div>
<footer> FOOTER
</footer>
```

Comment: I accept this answer... but I would also like to state, for the record... the THIS MAKES NO SENSE!  My div is INSIDE another div... therefore ABSOLUTE should work (but doesn't).  Having to set the position to relative, makes ABSOLUTELY NO SENSE.   It is no wonder everyone hates CSS.

Comment: @jason I know this is years old etc but I agree that this (still) makes no sense (but is sadly  still the case), I've had to realize that flexbox seems not to work with some other css stuff - like absolute positioning, you can only use realtive - it's bullsh*t but that's how it is up until now